# Screen refresh rate in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card

I am having problems with the refresh rate if the screen .

In the  the refresh mode of the monitor in the monitor options  have only one option 60Hz.

I have LG 24 + ATI Radon 3870, and have already installed the ATI driver via Ubuntu download center.

Any idea how I solve that one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LCD's doesent really have a [refresh rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate) as such so they usually (all the time?) only have one value to choose from.

From wikipedia *(highlight by me)*

> Much of the discussion of refresh rate
>   does not apply to the liquid crystal
>   portion of an LCD  monitor. This is
>   because while a CRT monitor uses the
>   same mechanism for both illumination
>   and imaging, LCDs employ a separate
>   backlight  to illuminate the image
>   being portrayed by the LCD's liquid
>   crystal shutters.
>
> `<snip>`
>
> The closest thing liquid crystal
>   shutters have to a refresh rate is
>   their response time, while nearly all
>   LCD backlights (most notably
>   fluorescent cathodes, which commonly
>   operate at ~200 Hz) have a separate
>   figure known as flicker, which
>   describes how many times a second the
>   backlight pulses on and off. **However
>   they also have a refresh rate that
>   governs how often a new image is
>   received from the video card (often at
>   60 Hz).**